# ERC-2309 Minting Multiple ERC-721 Tokens in one Transaction

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-721

Anyone know how to work with `ERC-2309`? It's an extension to the `ERC-721` Token standard and it's supposed to make it possible to mint a large number of `ERC-721` tokens (meaning 100's or even 1000's of them) in a SINGLE TRANSACTION.

This is particularly relevant these days (Autumn of 2020) as ETH gas prices have continued to skyrocket - making the launching of any project that requires multiple `ERC-721` tokens really *really* expensive. (And for some indie devs - downright impossible, which of course is really a shame.)

Below is a Contract I wrote with a `mintBatch()` function to try and test the minting of multiple 721's. It works just fine (in my `Truffle/Ganache` dev environment) when I mint 10, 20,  even 40 tokens in one shot - but at 50 I get the "out of gas" error. (This number seems to vary though as I run it in different times.)

Either way, how exactly is `ERC-2309` supposed to fit into all this? And, is my `mintBatch` function even the right way to go about doing this?

```
contract ColorToken is ERC721Full, Ownable {
  string public constant name = "ColorToken";
  string public constant symbol = "CLRT";


  struct RegularColor {
    uint8 red;
    uint8 green;
    uint8 blue;
  }


  RegularColor[] colorsArray;


  constructor() ERC721Full("ColorToken", "CLRT") public {

  }
  
  
  // Test mint function - intended to mint a bunch of ERC721 tokens all at once:
  function mintBatch(address ownerAddress, uint256 numColors) onlyOwner external {
    for(uint tempColorCounter = 0; tempColorCounter < numColors; tempColorCounter++) {
      // 1. Create a "random" RGB Color:
      RegularColor memory tempColor = RegularColor(uint8(now), uint8(now-28000), uint8(now+12500));
      // 2. Push the new color to the colorsArray:
      colorsArray.push(tempColor);
      // 3. Finally, MINT a new ERC721 Token:
      super._mint(msg.sender, tempColorCounter);
    }

  }


  function getColorOfTokenWithID(uint tokenID) public view returns(uint8 rd, uint8 gr, uint8 bl) {
    return (colorsArray[tokenID].red, colorsArray[tokenID].green, colorsArray[tokenID].blue);
  }



}
```

=========================

UPDATED CODE:

```
  // Moved my minting FOR loop into the Constructor so that all 
  // my NFT's get minted upon this Contract's Creation/Deployment:

constructor() ERC721Full("ColorToken", "CLRT") public {
    
    for(uint tempColorCounter = 0; tempColorCounter < 50; tempColorCounter++) {
      // 1. Create a "random" RGB Color:
      RegularColor memory tempColor = RegularColor(uint8(now), uint8(now-28000), uint8(now+12500));
      // 2. Push the new color to the colorsArray:
      colorsArray.push(tempColor);
      // 3. Finally, MINT a new ERC721 Token:
      super._mint(msg.sender, tempColorCounter);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

> Anyone know how to work with ERC-2309?

Yes. The standard is fully specified at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2309. That is how you work with it.

> `super._mint(msg.sender, tempColorCounter);`

This line is not using the ERC-2309 standard because that `_mint` implementation is emitting an event each time. You will need to rewrite your minting implementation if you want to use ERC-2309.

> Either way, how exactly is ERC-2309 supposed to fit into all this?

ERC-2309 allows you to save the gas associated with emitting N events to create N tokens. A very creative implementation is then able to create N tokens with O(1) resources.

Also note, the original ERC-721 implementation already allows O(1) token creation, but only during contract deployment, as specified in ERC-721, and cited in ERC-2309: "Exception: during contract creation, any number of NFTs may be created and assigned without emitting Transfer."

Comment: Really important what you pointed out: that "the original ERC-721 implementation already allows O(1) token creation, but only during contract deployment." Frankly, that suits my needs perfectly cause I'm just looking to mint all my NFT's on deployment - and that's it.  So I  moved my minting `for` loop right to the `constructor` (see my updated code), tried to mint only 50 NFT's (I'm eventually looking to mint like 2,000) - and I still ran out of gas and the deployment failed. So - is `ERC-2309` supposed to help me with this somehow?

Comment: You said my line `super._mint(msg.sender, tempColorCounter);` is not `ERC-2309` compliant and that I “need to rewrite your minting implementation if you want to use ERC-2309”.  Do you mean actually go to the original `ERC721.sol` file and replace the `emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);` line in the `mint` function there with `ERC-2309`’s `emit ConsecutiveTransfer(1, 100000, address(0), toAddress);` ? Or something along those lines? That's how we're supposed to use this standard? And is that going to prevent my contract’s deployment from running out of gas?

Comment: (really looking to understand this; feel like I'm just groping in the dark...)

Comment: Yes. The ERC-2309 standard is ^^NOT^^ backwards compatible with ERC-721. Therefore you cannot use any reference ERC-721 implementation as-is to implement ERC-2309. You must create your own implementation. Don't mess up! The ERC-721 implementation has been reviewed thoroughly and has open cash bounties to fix anything that may be wrong with it. A new implementation should be reviewed and confirmed high-quality before deployment.

Answer (score -1):

When do we use ERC 2309 instead of ERC1155? Minting website Cargo has this option for ERC 2309. Do you know?

Comment: Please ask new questions here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask